Why are these firebugs going inside those fruit?
These insects (Pyrrhocoris apterus) seem to love these dry hollow fruit. I think that those fruit are of Koelreuteria paniculata and mildly toxic to humans. I think that the Kolreutetia intertwines with a yew tree, giving the peculiar impression of those “lanterns” on a yew.
The insects seemed pretty immobile and it was around dusk. Are they going there for shelter?



